# How to use global / static variables OBJ-C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm looking to save a variable that is used for one method, and then call it in another method for an App. Does this have something to do with global/extern/static variables? If so, I was wondering how it would be set up. I've tried to use global and static with no success.

I'm trying to hold the information of newX and newY

```
-(void) accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{
...
    int newX = (int)(Button.center.x + valueX);
    int newY = (int)(Button.center.y + valueY);
...
}
```

and then call it in

```
-(IBAction)clicked:(id)sender

{
    randX = arc4random() % 320;
    randY = arc4random() % 548;

    CGPoint randNewPlace = CGPointMake(randX, randY);
    Rand.center = randNewPlace;



    if (newX == randX || newY  == randY)
    {
        [Rand sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
}
```

thanks.

Comment: just make newX and newY as properties within the ViewController. DONE!

Comment: ha.. u r correct.. he can use asper his wish :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do as below

Declare properties

```
@property(nonatomic,weak) int newX;
@property(nonatomic,weak) int newY;

-(void) accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{
...
    self.newX = (int)(Button.center.x + valueX);
    self.newY = (int)(Button.center.y + valueY);
...

}

-(IBAction)clicked:(id)sender

{
   randX = arc4random() % 320;
   randY = arc4random() % 548;

   CGPoint randNewPlace = CGPointMake(randX, randY);
   Rand.center = randNewPlace;

   if (self.newX == randX || self.newY  == randY)
   {
      [Rand sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use properties here. I have no clue why so many devs are in love with properties when they're quite a bit slower than just an iVar.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII The same reason Java developers write setters & getters for everything even if they can use public variables anywhere. Encapsulation.

Comment: @Sulthan in this situation there's no encapsulation to be done! When dealing with UIViewControllers, there is rarely a time when you ever need to subclass them, making said 'encapsulation' worthless in this scenario. Also, when you consider that you make the properties private anyways, as an implementation detail, it reduces the need for properties altogether!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define an unchanging constant variable define it in your .h and .m

For example, if i want to define the color black as a hexadecimal string in my .h I put above the **@interface**.

```
// Default Black
extern NSString * const Black;
```

---

Then in my .m above the **@implementation**

```
// Default Black
NSString * const Black      = @"0xFF000000";
```

Any time I call the variable **Black**, out comes **0xFF000000**
Of course you could define any type of variable, it doesn't have to be an NSString. `extern` simply exposes your variables to the rest of your application.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

@property (nonatomic) int newX,newY;

To access them just instantiate the class then use dot notation. Class.newX